# pack/unpack a generator

Tags: python

I have a two generators. First generator sometimes needs to call second generator and yield back values it got from there:

```
def a():
    for _b in b():
        yield _b

def b():
    yield 1
    yield 2

for _a in a():
    print _a
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this:

```
for _b in b():
    yield _b
```

I've tried this:

```
yield *b()
```

But surely it doesn't work. I have Python 2.6.

Comment: Are you actually trying to return (yield) everything from `b()` at once?

Comment: Yes, i am trying in a() to yield all values i get from b().

Comment: `a()` is a callback function of a scrapy spider (http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/spiders.html#topics-spiders)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean [PEP380](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/). It's [available from Python 3.3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.3.html). It looks like:

```
 yield from b()
```

There is no special syntax for that in Python2. You just use a for-loop.

The `a` function in your question is actually completely useless. You can just use `b` in it's place.

Comment: In real code (scrapy spider method) `a` yields some values of its own. i guess if there is a PEP, this means that the problem is known, and there is no elegant solution for now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a generator expression.  It's about as concise as the loop, plus it indicates that your code is primarily for producing a return value instead of a side effect.

```
def a():
    return (_b for _b in b())
```

As phihag said, you can probably simply write `a = b` if your code is really like this example, since a and b return the same sequence.

Comment: the `a` you wrote is a builtin called `iter`

Comment: `return (_b for _b in b())` is more easily (and efficiently) written as `return b()`, and it doesn't work if `a` is a generator function itself (as the question states.)

Comment: yes, that doesn't work, as it yields a value of type <generator>

Comment: Can you give me an example of a situation where this `a` behaves differently from the original?  They both work in `for _a in a(): print _a`, and both tell me that `type(a())` is 'generator'.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in this simple example, you could just write `a = b` or `a = lambda: b`. But if `a` adds elements of its own, you can use [itertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import itertools
def a():
  return itertools.chain(['a-value'], b())
```

Bear in mind that although this variant may be shorter, `for: yield` is a quite intuitive (and therefore easy to understand) pattern.